# Add primary key to an existing table

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert, primary-key

How to add a primary key to an existing table in SQLite? I know that I have to generate a new table and copy everything from the old table. However, it keeps giving me an error saying datatype mismatch due to one table having a primary key and the other one not. I did run the same commands without including primary key and it works.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    age INTEGER, 
    address TEXT
)

INSERT INTO temp_table 
    SELECT * 
    FROM original_table
```

Since I am importing the data from a CSV file I do not know how to add the PRIMARY KEY in the first place. In case anyone knows a solution for that it would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the original table has 2 columns: `age` and `address`, you can either list the column names of the new table without the primary key:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table(age, address) 
SELECT age, address FROM original_table
```

or, include the primary key and pass `null` for its value:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table(id, age, address) 
SELECT null, age, address FROM original_table
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table
SELECT null, age, address FROM original_table
```

In all cases the `id` will be filled by SQLite, because it is defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and it will be automatically autoincremented starting from 1.

If there is another column in the original table with unique integer values, you can pass that column to fill the new `id`:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table(id, age, address) 
SELECT col, age, address FROM original_table
```

Change `col` to the actual name of the column.

Comment: So there is no way to pass values from a certain variable in the original table to the primary key in the new table?

Comment: @MoritzVoss you can pass a value to the primary key of a table, but you have defined the id as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY which for SQLite means that it will be auto incremented, starting from 1.

Comment: Ah ok. So how would it work if I want to pass INTEGER values to the primary key from the original table without auto incrementing? Sorry for being so vague but unfortunately I cannot post the original data nor variable names

Comment: @MoritzVoss is there a column in the original table with unique integer values?

Comment: Yes, there is a column with a unique identifier.

Comment: @MoritzVoss check my last query.

Comment: It works if I give col no specific datatype and then insert thanks!

Comment: @MoritzVoss only integer values can be inserted to a column defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. If the values that you want to insert are not integers but strings then you should define the column as TEXT although SQLite accepts column definitions without a specific data type.

Comment: They are INTEGER values but if I define them as INTEGER values in the temp table then I have the same problem as stated above.

Comment: I do not see the difference between what you wrote INSERT INTO temp_table(id, age, address) 
SELECT col, age, address FROM original_table and what I wrote INSERT INTO temp_table 
    SELECT * 
    FROM original_table because id and col are the same in my example I just want it to be clearly defined as the PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @MoritzVoss Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=59320ccd3dc8417c6981f134ed02bf22 If the original id contains unique integer values then you should not get any problem even if you define the new id as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. For `SELECT * FROM...` it would also work if the order of the 3 columns is the same as in the new table. So, if you are getting errors maybe the problem is something else.